# Unable to access the web-cam functionality over http in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, http, ejs

So I've a simple Node.js backend alongside an EJS frontend where I simply want to turn on the camera of the user when the click a button upon landing on a page.

The code works fine when testing over `localhost:port` however I've another requirement wherein I want the site to be available to all other devices on the same network/wifi.

So when I put `http://IP_ADDRESS:port` the site loads up but when the user hits the button, the camera doesn't turn on, upon checking the browser's site settings.

[image: site permissions]

I find that the camera enabling setting is greyed out and won't allow camera permission for **privacy reasons**. Is there any way around this?

I only want the code to work for a set of users connected on the same network, not globally.

**app.js**

```
app.get('/cam-feed', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home');
});


wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('Client connected');

    ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
        saveFrame(data);
    });
});

function saveFrame(imageData) {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(imageData.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''), 'base64');
    fs.writeFile('frame.jpg', buffer, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error saving frame:', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Frame saved successfully');
        }
    });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**home.ejs**

```
<body>
    <h1>Camera Feed</h1>
    <button id="startButton">Start Camera</button>
    <video id="videoElement" style="display: none;" autoplay></video>

    <script>
        const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
        const video = document.getElementById('videoElement');
        let stream;

        startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            startCamera();
        });

        function startCamera() {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(function (videoStream) {
                    stream = videoStream;
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.style.display = 'block';
                    setInterval(() => captureFrame(), 1000); // Capture frame every second
                    startButton.disabled = true; // Disable button after starting camera
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('Error accessing the camera:', err);
                });
        }

        function captureFrame() {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); // Convert frame to base64 JPEG
            // Check if stream is active before sending frame
            if (stream.active) {
                ws.send(imageData); // Send frame to server
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: That's because [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) feature is only available in secure contexts (HTTPS). It worked on `localhost` because "*Locally-delivered resources such as those with `http://127.0.0.1` URLs, `http://localhost` and `http://*.localhost` URLs (e.g. `http://dev.whatever.localhost/`), and `file://` URLs are also considered to have been delivered securely.*" [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)